# Display two divs on mobile devices, but hide one on desktop, using media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my project I have two divs (i.e  **#div1, #div2**). I want to show both divs on mobile devices and only **#div1** on desktop devices.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #div1 {
            display: none;
        }
}
```

In this case, work as desktop show- **#div1,#div2** and mobile showing **#div2**.

But I want desktop to show **#div1**, and mobile to show **#div1,#div2**

How can write a @media-query for this. I can't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/* mobile first */

.div1, .div2 {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: tan;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .div1{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
```

You have it just swap out min for max in the media query.